# Using getsupportfragmentmanager() while extending SlidingMenu?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragmentactivity, slidingmenu

I have a bit of a problem here; I want to use the SlidingMenu on my activity + the ViewPagerIndicator ... but I cannot use the getsupportfragmentmanager() without extending FragmentActivity or I cannot use getSlidingMenu() without extending SlidingActivity..

Is there any work arround to use getsupportfragmentmanager() without extending FragmentActivity or it isn't even possible?

Thanks in advance

(If anyone is interested ill post the code)

EDIT:

I solved the problem;

I went to SlidingActivity.java in the library and changed "extends Activity" to "extends FragmentActivity" and it worked..